# android - Why does view.bringToFront() doenst work in custom Listview case?

Tags: android-widget

I am making a custom listview, in that data is dynamically changing after sometime. this part and click event part of list and list's button is working fine.I have to show some specific row on the top according to text.

I am using `view.bringToFront()` for showing that row in front. It is not working. How can i do this?? I want `if(StatusText.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("chat request"))` if i check this method then this row come to front as top row of the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bringToFront() change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views (pay attention: Z-order) In your case you should resort your data and call notifyDataChanged for your adapter

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use relative layout with  listview and list item layout.Make Listitem layout invisible.After calling that method just make the visiblity of that listitem layout to View.VISIBLE as you are using relative layout you can position the list item layout to top bottom center or anywer.